# Subcategory list with Magento Flat Catalog

Tags: magento

I'm using the code below to get a list of categories on the same level as the current page (by listing the subcategories of this category's parent). It works great when Flat Categories are off. Once I enable Flat Categories, the H2 works correctly, but the list changes to display the *root's* subcategories instead of *this page's parent's* subcategories. What am I doing wrong, and why does it act this way?

```
<?php
$_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
$parentCategoryId = $_category->getParentId();
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($parentCategoryId);
$helper     = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$parentCategory   = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentCategoryId);

?>
<h2><?php echo $parentCategory->getName(); ?></h2>

<ul>
<?php foreach ($collection as $cat):?>
        <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
            <li <?php
                if ($cat->getId() == $_category->getId()) {
                    echo 'class="current"';
                }
            ?>>
                <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($cat);?>"><?php echo $cat->getName();?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

Yes, I've flushed the cache and indexes.

Comment: Is there another method instead of "getParentId()"? You can find it out by using `get_class_methods(get_class($_category))` - maybe there is another, similiar sounding method which works better in your case ...

Comment: I will take a look, but the <h2> using $parentCategory->getName() populates correctly. I would think that means getParentID() is working, $parentCategoryId is correct, and the problem somehow lies with the $collection = ... line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't completely know why ->getCategories($id) is not "flat-safe", but using Stefan's suggestion helped me find an alternate method for this instead.

My new lines at top look like this:

```
$_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
$parentCategoryId = $_category->getParentId();
$helper     = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$parentCategory   = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentCategoryId);
$collection = $parentCategory->getChildrenCategories();
```

... which works regardless of 'flat catalog' on or off.

Comment: As we say in The Netherlands, you've helped me out of the fire! :D